# Conventions for ToString

Tags: c#, tostring, conventions

What are the conventions for `ToString()` overrides? The class in question has both a `Name` property, but also an `Id`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can refer to following links

[Overriding System.Object.ToString() and Implementing IFormattable](http://codebetter.com/davidhayden/2005/02/24/overriding-system-object-tostring-and-implementing-iformattable/)

[Demystifying C# Programming's ToString Method](http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/article.php/c18377/Demystifying-C-Programmings-ToString-Method.htm)

[How To: Override the ToString Method](https://web.archive.org/web/20121112153254/http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173154(v=vs.80).aspx)

My Rule of thumb

1. It should be in sync with [Equals](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bsc2ak47.aspx) and [GetHashCode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.gethashcode.aspx)
2. It should be in sync with Parse method (If I am providing)
3. Use IFormattable if custom formatting is needed

Answer (score 7):

Do what you need to do. There's no convention per-se, as there is when overriding something like `.Equals()` and `.GetHashCode()`.

If you want to influence what appears in the debugger when you break during execution, don't use `ToString()` - use [`DebuggerDisplayAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debuggerdisplayattribute.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about any convention. I usually print what seems appropriate in a textual context. The `Id` might and might not be appropriate for your context.

My rule of thumb is that the `ToString` should reveal if two objects are `Equals` or not.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know the conventions for `ToString()` are intrinsicly linked ot the conventions for the other 2 overridable methods on object - `GetHashCode` and `Equals`.

That is to say that when `Equals` returns true, then the same hash code should be generated by `GetHashCode`. To add to this, I would say that when `Equals` returns true, `ToString` should return the same string.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the implementation of `ToString()` should keep in mind three things:

- The string representation should be readable by human, e.g. you could use it for log/console output or for example in **[DebuggerDisplay](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228992.aspx)** attribute.
- If you have any `Parse` method in your class, it should be able to parse the result of a `ToString` call. Furthermore `myInstance.Equals(MyClass.Parse(myInstance.ToString()))` should evaluate as `true`
- If two instances are equal, their string representation should also be equal.

Answer (score 0):

There is some guidance here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173154(v=vs.80).aspx

I think it comes down a lot to how the class is intended to be used though.  For example, if it is displayed oriented then the return needs to be relevant for users who might end up seeing it.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a uniform and reusable solution for all your ToString methods across the entire application. Hand code a general ToStringHelper or use an external library such as the stateprinter project https://github.com/kbilsted/StatePrinter project